# What am i missing in this java code?

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison

```
if (array[i]<(char)65 || array[i]>(char)122 && 
                               array[i]>(char)91 || array[i]<=(char)96)
  System.out.println("False")
```

in this code, when i try to assign character 'C' (which is 67 btw) to array[i] it still says false. I did the math and it's not supposed to print "false" as I stated below this line.

```
(67 < 65 = 0 || 67 > 122 = 0) = 0

(67 > 91 = 0 || 67 <= 96 = 1) = 1
```

So, this leaves us: 0 & 1 = 0 .
Any ideas?

Comment: indentation, formatting, some parentheses, and a semicolon

Comment: How do you expect the many `&&` and `||` operators to interact with each other? Add some bracketing and I suspect you'll be okay...

Comment: Logical `&&` has higher precedence. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Ohh so that's why!. Thanks a lot. This has been bothering me for like 5 hours.

Comment: Try to use a more descriptive title name next time. People scrolling through questions will have no idea what this question is about without clicking on it. Even something like: "Java boolean expression giving unexpected result" is heaps better

Comment: Tiny aside: the easy way to remember boolean operator precedence is by recalling that `&&` is boolean multiplication, and `||` is boolean addition. (And hoping you don't encounter a language that ignores that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some formatting, your code is:

```
if ( array[i] < (char)65 || array[i] >  (char)122 &&
     array[i] > (char)91 || array[i] <= (char)96     )
  System.out.println("False");
```

Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||` (see [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)), this is equivalent to:

```
if (    array[i] <  (char)65
   || ( array[i] >  (char)122 && array[i] > (char)91 ) 
   ||   array[i] <= (char)96 )
  System.out.println("False");
```

which, since `&&` is short circuiting, is behaviorally equivalent to:

```
if (  array[i] < (char)65
   || array[i] > (char)122 
   || array[i] <= (char)96 )
  System.out.println("False");
```

which, since the last case covers the first, is logically equivalent to:

```
if ( array[i] > (char)122 || array[i] <= (char)96 )
  System.out.println("False");
```

You'll print `False` whenever the value it greater than 122 or less than or equal to 96.  67 is less than 96, so you print `False`.  As pointed out the in comments, there is a precedence to the operators.  Rather than learning all the details (to predict cases like this), it's easier just to use enough parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` is evaluated first, and then the `||` according to the [Java Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). So it gets evaluated the following way for 'C'

```
67>122 && 67>91 //false
67<65 || false //false
false || 67<=96 //true
```

if you uses parentheses it will solve this problem

```
if ((array[i]<(char)65 || array[i]>(char)122) && 
                           (array[i]>(char)91 || array[i]<=(char)96))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this by using brackets `()`:

```
if ((array[i]<(char)65 || array[i]>(char)122) && (array[i]>(char)91 || array[i]<=(char)96))
      System.out.println("False")
```

Also to note that `&&` has higher precedence